# how to implement localize_callback in flask login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I see the offical doc an it does not have any detail inplementation the callback.

http://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

> By default, the LoginManager uses flash to display messages when a
>   user is required to log in. These messages are in English. If you
>   require localization, set the localize_callback attribute of
>   LoginManager to a function to be called with these messages before
>   they’re sent to flash, e.g. gettext. This function will be called with
>   the message and its return value will be sent to flash instead.

and I try to use

```
@login_manager.localize_callback
def localize_callback():
    return 'local string'
```

when I'm doing this. it tells me

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

what's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adjust the code a little bit.and it works though not eligant

```
def localize_callback(*args, **kwargs):
    return 'local string'
login_manager.localize_callback = localize_callback
```

Comment: can you post a longer code piece including the @login_required decorator? Because for me it does nothing. Thanks.

Comment: @576i it's a long time ago, and my solution works on flask0.10. I don't have the code anymore cause I left the company a year ago. now I'm a full time django developer. but you can check the source code of flask-login ,it's simple code. or just ask the author on github. maybe they can help.